# Grunt file Concat and css min error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Am facing an error while doing a concat and css min using grunt. 
I added a myPage method/object, i dont know how to initialize that. 
Am new to grunt task, trying to learn and do it and i finally stuck here.

Here it is what I tried.

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        myPage: {
            concat: {
                css: {
                    src: 'common/css/*.css',
                    dest: 'common/css/concat.css'
                }
            },
            cssmin: {
                css: {
                    src: 'common/css/concat.css',
                    dest: 'common/css/concat.min.css'
                }
            }
        }        
    });
    grunt.registerTask('devbuild', function() {
        grunt.task.run(['concat:css','cssmin:css']);
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['devbuild']);

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["build"]);

};
```

Comment: `facing an error` which tells what? "You don't have enough candies"?

Comment: what are typing in the terminal to run the task?

Comment: so that just runs the default task, to run your dev build task type in `grunt devBuild` or put the concat/min stuff in there and then you can just run it with `grunt`

Comment: I tried: i am getting this error : 
Verifying property concat.css exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "concat.css" missing. Use --force to continue.

Answer (score 0):

This: `grunt.task.run(['concat:css','cssmin:css']);` would need to be `grunt.task.run(['myPage:concat:css','myPage:cssmin:css']);`

That said, having the myPage object in this case doesn't provide you with a whole lot of value.

Comment: Warning: Task "myPage:concat:css" not found. Use --force to continue. Am getting this warning and the task run is getting stop